# Fill the blank with an image that fits into the given set

Tags: pattern, visual, geometry, progressive-matrix

I tried to make them not too boring. The intended solution is very hard so I tried to slightly hint at it by implementing multiple solutions that lead to the same answer. I also tried to make more images to make it more obvious or more decidable.

[image: Shapes, Ordering, Spatial]

[image: Conditionals, Rulesets, 1]

[image: Conditionals. Rulesets, 2]

[image: Conditionals, Negation]

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

> 3, 2, 4, 3

Explanations:

First:

> Two images are paired up but the order in which the items are stacked might be changed. A purple circle means that the items are stacked from top to bottom in the order they appear from left to right. A blue circle flips that order and makes it right to left. Notice that the banana-shaped thing appears slightly before the surfboard if you go to the left from the right. Also notice that the banana appears before the surfboard if you go from left to right. This means that the banana will always be above the oval surfboard.

Second:

> Extend all black lines to infinity and count the number of intersections between all the lines. (Only the lines) If # is even, make the shapes purple. If # is odd, make them blue. Only the second picture satisfies this. (#=0 and purple)

Third:

> Count the intersections. (Any intersection!) If the # is bigger or equal to 2: purple. If there are no intersections or there is only 1: blue. Touching shapes (tangent lines, etc.) count as 1 intersection.

Last:

> If there is a checkmark in the top right:
>  Number of triangles in the image: odd -> purple. even -> blue. If there is no checkmark: the rules above were followed incorrectly. Notice that two overlapping triangles make at least one additional triangle that has to be counted.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling stackexchange. In Puzzling stackexchange answering your own questions without any hints is not fair to other people solving this puzzle. Although it is fine to answer your own puzzle there should be a reasonable amount of time so other people have a chance to solve. A reasonable  amount time will be a week then add hints. If the question is not answered for months you can set a bounty (if you have the amount of rep points for that). for more information please visit [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/78801).

Comment: @VarunW. Yeah I noticed that a day after posting and surfing some other threads. My newer puzzle won’t have it’s answer released for a longer time. Thanks for reminding me. Should I delete this answer as there is another person who has managed to pretty much almost solve all of them?

Comment: That is your choice, but just dont do it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Answers are as follows...

Puzzle 1:

> Box 4. The layering shifts down a level by one each, and since the oval was on bottom in the first image it moved to the top.

Puzzle 2:

> Box 2. Extending the lines until they intersect with the squares, and then counting every intersection (including with the squares) if the count of intersections is odd then the color is blue, otherwise it's purple. Box 2 has no lines, so 0 is purple. The only one that throw me off is the box in the examples that is down one from the upper left. I'm assuming that the lines are supposed to intersect at the same point along the upper-right hand side of the box they are in.

Puzzle 3:

> Box 4. When there are 2 intersecting or touchings then the circle turns purple. Box 4 is the only one that fits.

Puzzle 4:

> Box 1. Count all possible triangles (so if two intersecting triangles make another triangle, count them separately. If the count is odd, make them purple, if the count is even make them blue. If that rule is followed, there's a check mark at the top, otherwise if the color is wrong then there's no check.

Comment: Your first explanation doesn't work if you try it on each of the examples. Your last explanation is correct but the answer you picked is wrong. Number 1 has 5 triangles -> purple. But the color is actually blue. (+checkmark) It's the other one that is similar but with a different color.

Comment: Also to add to your second explanation: The example you are referencing has 5 intersections (some out of the box). That makes it blue.